# External USB touch screen recognizing touch events but only responding to edge swipes

Tags: usb, touchscreen

I have an LG G8X I'm trying to get working with an external USB IR touch frame and it's been driving me bonkers for weeks... I feel like I'm so close to figuring it out, yet so far at the same time.

If I turn on "Show touches" and "Show touch data" in developer options and proceed to use the IR touch frame, it shows all touch events as expected and multitouch works fine. The problem is that my taps and swipes don't actually do anything -- I can't click, I can't scroll, nothing works EXCEPT if a do a swipe gesture from the edge of the IR frame. This means that I can perform a "back" or "home/recent apps" gesture just fine...

I've tested the IR touch frame with my S23 Ultra and it works perfectly fine. I've tested a different external touchscreen monitor on the G8X which also worked as expected.

I've run "adb shell getevent -l" and the events seem to be registering fine:

```
add device 8: /dev/input/event7
  name:     "Touch p303 Keyboard"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
add device 9: /dev/input/event8
  name:     "Touch p303"
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00004690
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00005cc8
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000090
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR   00000090
/dev/input/event8: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_X                00004690
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_Y                00005cc8
/dev/input/event8: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00004748
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00005ba8
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_X                00004748
/dev/input/event8: EV_ABS       ABS_Y                00005ba8
```

I've created an *.idc file per [this documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/input/input-device-configuration-files), but have had difficulty finding what properties I can even change. My config is as follows:

```
touch.deviceType = touchScreen
touch.orientationAware = 1
touch.gestureMode = spots
```

I've confirmed the .idc file is being used, but as expected, this didn't change the behaviour. The strange thing is if I change the touch.deviceType to 'pointer' it works exactly as I would expect -- it turns into a large trackpad with a mouse cursor displayed on screen and I can actually 'click' on items...

I've also checked out `dmesg` and `adb shell dumpsys input`, comparing the different touch screens and different phones, but nothing seemed out of the ordinary (with my limited knowledge anyway...).

Any hints on what might be the issue or further steps I can take to troubleshoot would be much appreciated!